# Запустить Perl-скрипт на Windows

Tags: perl

Добрый Вечер!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно запустить данный [скрипт](https://github.com/kud/jpegrescan/blob/master/jpegrescan) на Windows?

У меня установлен ActivePerl 5.16.3 Build 1603 с установленными File::Slurp и File::Temp.
Как я понимаю, проблема в [JPEGtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/), но я не понимаю куда его надо положить?

Comment: А что не получается-то? А то у меня не винды, проблемы не вижу. Из командной строки cmd.exe этот самый jpegtran запускается? Если нет, то с указанием пути до этого скрипта? Если запускается с указанием пути типа `C:/blabla/jpegtran`, то и написать и в `open tran "-|", "C:/blabla/jpegtran"

С обратными слешами `\` -- аккуратней. Их придётся ставить два там, где нужен один

Comment: Из командной строки jpegtran запускается, не понимаю в чем проблема.

Нашел новую версию скрипта, выдает теперь ошибки
http://pastebin.com/pe33VFgj

http://habrastorage.org/storage3/063/0ad/3ab/0630ad3ab404b0824c5b8049155c3c00.png